# iterrows() producing empty column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to use `iterrows()` in a for loop to add data to a new column within a dataframe. However, this sadly produces just a new empty column. I am not entirely sure where I am going wrong here. When you run the code, `print(row['Key_words'])` output values, so its not like there isn't any data in the new column because there is nothing to add.

I am not sure what's going wrong here. The frustrating part is this has worked just fine for me in the past. I am wondering if there are any revisions to the code/alternative solutions to solve this problem?

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}, 'name': {0: 'Sandwich Cookies', 1: 'All-Seasons Salt', 2: 'Unsweetened Oolong Tea'}, 'a_id': {0: 'cookies cakes', 1: 'spices seasonings', 2: 'tea'}, 'd_id': {0: 'snacks', 1: 'pantry', 2: 'beverages'}})
```

Example code:

```
df['Key_words'] = ''
i = 1
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row['Key_words'] = list(str(i))
    i = i + 1
    print(row['Key_words'])

df
```

Comment: Iterating over a pandas df is generally speaking not a good idea (performance-wise). What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @DocZerø I'm really just trying to add new data to the new column `Key_words`

Comment: The empty column is created by the first line. If you want to add data to the row in this way you should do  df.loc[index, 'Key_words'] = list(str(i)), however, as DocZero mentioned, this is very slow. Beter to first create a list of the data and add that to the data frame in one go

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df['Key_words'] = ''
i = 1
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[index, 'Key_words'] = list(str(i))
    i = i + 1
    print(row['Key_words'])

df
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the issue without having to resort to iterating row by row. This assumes that your index is as shown in your post (thus starting from 0).

```py
df['key_words'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.name+1, axis=1)
```

|  | id | name | a_id | d_id | key_words |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Sandwich Cookies | cookies cakes | snacks | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | All-Seasons Salt | spices seasonings | pantry | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | Unsweetened Oolong Tea | tea | beverages | 3 |